# Is it possible to find "castaway" accommodation in the Alps?

Tags: accommodation, where-on-earth, alps, nostalgia

After watching the last episodes of [*Breaking Bad*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breaking_Bad), I've had the idea of finding a truly castaway house to stay in for a week or so. Preferably something with electricity, running water and Internet, yet zero neighbours in the immediate vicinity.

Is it possible to find such accommodation somewhere in the Alps?

Obviously one could set-up a tent in the middle of the woods, but that's not the solution I'm looking for.

Comment: What kind of range do you consider "immediate vicinity"?  Americans or Australians can get locations hours drive from the neighbours, but it's less likely in more crowded Europe where five minutes might be isolated.

Comment: I would define 'isolated' as being at least 500 meters away from the nearest neighbor. And obviously there should be no major roads/hiking trails passing close to the house.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is definitely possible. I grew up in the Alps and I can think of at least a dozen places like that.

The problem is that most of them are privately owned and it might not be so easy to get access to one. There is a [website](http://www.sentiero.ch/de65_berghuetten-schweiz_miete-kauf.htm) about renting such huts in Switzerland, but unfortunately the listings are only in German. Note that even if some of the houses are not totally isolated you can be quite sure to be alone if you go there in low season during the week as those are nowadays mostly used as holiday homes.

You should be looking into something which is accessible only by walking to increase your chances of being let alone. Note that most of those places will have running water (water being abundant in the Alps), maybe electricity via a solar panel but most likely no Internet.

Answer (score 7):

The answer appears to be yes, you just need to search for them and be willing to limit your definition of "isolated" given the crowdedness of the Alps.

[This chalet](http://www.homeaway.co.uk/p1039268) is a great example - no immediate neighbours but [all the mod cons](http://www.homeaway.co.uk/p1039268#amenities).  However it's probably still within five minutes of the nearest people, given there's a train station 2 km away.